# entitymanagerfactory is closed after refreshing ConfigurableApplicationContext

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security

I'm building a web application using Spring MVC. I've been trying to come up with a way to customise some system properties and reload the web application without restarting the Tomcat server.

Currently, I'm doing this task by using refresh() method in ConfigurableApplicationContext and its working at the moment.

```
@Autowired
ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext;
```

..

```
public void reloadConfigurations() {
    configurableApplicationContext.refresh();
}
```

However, if the user logs out after refreshing the system, then after that he will not able to login to the system again.

Here's the message I get as `SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION` :

> entitymanagerfactory is closed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.illegalstateexception: entitymanagerfactory is closed.

Can't see any other errors in system logs or tomcat log.

Here's the code

application-cotext.xml

```
<bean id="mysqlDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mysqlDataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myAppMySql" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.myApp.model" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="myAppMySql" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.myApp.model.SystemConfig</class>
    <class>com.myApp.model.User</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="5"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="10"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Any ideas?? Thanks in advance

Comment: You would need to refresh all the contexts both the root and the parent. Instead of trying to hack your way around I would say it is probably easier, safer and as fast to just restart the application. I would also suggest to take a look at spring boot and the spring cloud config parts of spring cloud (maybe you can use that for inspiration).

Comment: Thank you @M.Deinum . What did you mean by _"You would need to refresh all the contexts both the root and the parent."_ 
Could you please explain this, a bit further.

Comment: Yuo probably have a `ContextLoaderListener` and a `DispatcherServlet` if you only refresh one of those you will run into weird to debug issues. Not to mention that you might run into class loading issues and memory leaks with this.

Comment: So does that mean we can't use refresh() method in ConfigurableApplicationContext to reload system properties?

Comment: Well you can but I would really advice against it.